# Is there a transform similar to the shearlet transform that uses a rotation matrix rather than shearing?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, wavelets

I Have been working in wavelet and shearlet analysis for the past couple of months. However I am working in the analysis side rather than the numerics side. In my work I have been considering the geometry of the shearlet coefficients due to the scaling, shearing and translation. However I have found that the scaling and shearing both affect the overall size of the shearlet domain.

I have been told that there exists a transform that utilizes a rotation matrix rather than a shearing matrix to control the orientation of the analysing functions. However when looking online I can't find such a transform. Does such a transform actually exist and if it does what is it called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for **curvelets** (or ridgelets). They are well suited for approximating functions with jump across smooth curves but don't have a group structure like wavelets or shearlets.

Comment: Yep!! They look like exactly what I need. Thank you!!